# Interface Builder layout UIViewController xib for orientation change in top bar height

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I created a new .xib file for a UIViewController subclass, left everything at defaults and added a couple of buttons near the top of the view, but allowing for the height of status bar + navbar.  When I push this from my UITableViewController rootController in portrait mode all is fine.  But, when I rotate the iPhone to landscape, the view layout does not adjust for the shorter top bar in landscape mode, so there is extra space between buttons and nav bar.  I know I can fix this programmatically, but there must be a simple way to automate this, something wrong with the way I am setting up my xib.  Isn't there a way to lay out the view independently of top bar height?

Answer (score 0):

You can use auto layout to fix this problem.

1. Select the button on the view
2. Find the pin icon on the bottom of the screen (bottom right, second icon in the set of four). Click it.
3. Click the faded red line that is pointing upwards, and then hit add 1 constraint.
4. Go to the next icon to the left of the pin icon (called align).
5. Choose the horizontally centered option and hit add 1 constraint.

This will create a button that is centered horizontally and will stay the same distance from the top no matter what orientation the device is.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but it does not solve my problem.  It does fix the button position relative to the top of the view.  But I want it fixed relative to the bottom of the navBar, which the system changes according to orientation.  Isn't there some way to say the top of my view should be at bottom of navbar rather than top of screen?

Comment: First, make sure you are using size classes. If not, click the .xib and open the file inspector. Then check the size classes option. You can then drag the button right below the navigation bar. Follow the same steps in the answer.

Comment: Same problem with size classes enabled.  I have another .xib that contains only a UITableView, and IB shows it filling the view, not leaving space for navigation bar.  This does adjust itself to just touch bottom of navbar. I guess UITableViewController may be handling this programmatically… or I will look in xib for clues.

Comment: In the document outline, are the buttons in each .xib in the same place/order? I think that's what's changing things.

Comment: See my answer above, problem was due to iOS default setting that navBar/status bar are translucent so content should be positioned relatives to top of screen, not bottom of navbar.  There was a flurry of postings about this when iOS 7 was first introduced… I mistakenly believed these were just transition issues and that Xcode would now do what I want by default.

Answer (score 0):

Could not figure out Interface Builder, but was able to fix the problem by just creating the UIViewController programmatically, and setting self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;  This tells the view controller not to extend the view under the navBar.  Probably this works with IB as well, but IB seems to be nothing but a headache.  The nice thing about code is you can google, copy, paste and re-use it.  And there are systematic procedures for obsolescence and upgrade, unlike a GUI where features come and go haphazardly.

Comment: Good points! I'm going to look into how to do this with IB because it could come in handy.

Comment: btw, handy trick for seeing what is going on with issues like this is: self.view.layer.borderWidth = 2; self.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;  Then you can see exactly what is happening with view dimensions.